# python shell restarts when using plt.close('all')

Tags: python, shell, matplotlib

I am using interactive figure plotting with matploitlib in python, but when I close all figures, directly or by using plt.close('all'), the shell restarts. For example:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.figure()
<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x0000000003732828>
>>> plt.figure()
<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x00000000037327B8>
>>> plt.close('all')

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>>
```

What do I do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Can you please add some more information: what version of `python` and `matplotlib` are you using? What platform are you on?

Comment: The installation is: WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5